# Prisma MySQL NextJS/ReactJS - Results from query in loop aren't being saved

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm having a problem with a Prisma query and I can't get my head around why it won't work.

The following method getImages() retrieves all the images of a product.

**Query**

```
  const getImages = async (id) => {
    return await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM product_image WHERE product_id = ${id}`;
  };
```

I'm trying to do the following, I want to retrieve all products, where every product has all its images in the result. However when I do the following, "images" is simply not stored in any product. Note: 81 is a hardcoded id, it would be replaced with product.id but neither works.

**GET method (doesn't work)**

```
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    let products = await prisma.product.findMany();

    const index = 0;
    products.forEach(async (product) => {
      const images = await getImages(81);
      products[index++]["images"] = await images;
    });
    
    return res.send(products);
  }
```

The funny thing is, the following does work. So I can retrieve the images of product 81 and then store it into every product in product.images.

**GET method (works)**

```
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    let products = await prisma.product.findMany();
    const images = await getImages(81);

    const index = 0;
    products.forEach(async (product) => {
      products[index++]["images"] = images;
    });

    return res.send(products);
  }
```

Can anyone explain why the first method won't work?

Comment: Just a curiosity, why not use Raw Join or Prisma Relation Queries
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have an async function inside `.forEach` that is not being awaited, so `res.send` will be called before the query is complete.

Does this work?

```js
if (req.method == "GET") {
  let products = await prisma.product.findMany();

  products = await Promise.all(
    products.map(async (product) => {
      const images = await getImages(product.id);
      return {
        ...product,
        images,
      };
    }),
  );

  return res.send(products);
}
```

Even better however would be to join the images in the first query.